# Hibernate Timestamp with Timezone

Tags: oracle, hibernate, time, timezone, timestamp

I'm new to Hibernate and am working with an Oracle 10g database. We have columns in our tables that are of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. Hibernate does not seem to support this mapping directly. Is there a standard way to go about this?

Answer (score 5):

An example of a UserType storing java.util.Calendar with time zone information is given in this blog post: http://www.joobik.com/2010/12/mapping-dates-and-time-zones-with.html

Comment: don't post just a link otherwise your answer is worthless if the link breaks

Comment: Updated link: http://www.joobik.com/2010/12/mapping-dates-and-time-zones-with.html

Answer (score 2):

`TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` is Oracle extension and thus is not supported by Hibernate out of the box. You have two options:

1) Change your table structure to store timezone in a separate column (as VARCHAR2). Hibernate is able to [map java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes) as `timezone` type using its ID.

2) Write a custom class to hold both timestamp and timezone and a custom [UserType](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) that would persist it. It will have to be a [CompositeUserType](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/v3/api/org/hibernate/usertype/CompositeUserType.html) if you need the ability to use its individual properties (e.g. timezone or timestamp) in queries. Look at [this example](https://www.hibernate.org/100.html) to get you started; you'll need to alter it to actually store the timezone.

Comment: According to SQL in a Nutshell by Kline et al, TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE is a type defined by SQL 2003. Thus, it's not an Oracle extension.

Comment: Call it "SQL 2003 extension implemented by Oracle" then. It's still not supported by Hibernate

Comment: java.util.Calendar holds both timestamp and time zone information. Therefore solution by joobik seems better to me.