# NHibernate support for TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE type in Oracle

Tags: nhibernate, oracle10g

Is it possible to map a .Net DateTime to a TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE type in Oracle using NHibernate? Looks like it's [not readily available in "Hibernate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289492/hibernate-timestamp-with-timezone)

If this is not available out of the box, can someone please direct to examples of how it may be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were not able to find a proper mapping to this using NHb 3.1. However extended support for times (including timezone etc...) is available for SQL Server '07 onwards.

Our solution was to use a varchar field instead of timestamp and format the dates to include the timezone information. The consumer of this data was able to handle this change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert them to UTC and store that.