# How to set timestamptz(timestamp with time zone) in postgres + hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

we have timestamptz field in table. Please tell me, How to set this field type in XML mapping? and Also how to add an entry to the column programatically?

**message** Table

```
CREATE TABLE message (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL,
        isprocessed INT4 DEFAULT 0,
        processed_date TIMESTAMPTZ,
        notecontents TEXT(2147483647),
        ack_date TIMESTAMPTZ
    );
```

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289492/hibernate-timestamp-with-timezone

Comment: @LeBarton Thank for quick response... I'm using XML mapping, I wanted to know how to map this type of field in .hbm file

Comment: The answer is still accurate. Hibernate only supports ansi SQL datatypes. Timestamptz is not part of the standard. You will either need to create a type mapper or change the column's data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Timestamp with Timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289492/hibernate-timestamp-with-timezone)